# how to add vertical line between two divs

Tags: css

I want to make a vertical line between two `div`s. we have `hr` for horizontal line but none for vertical line as I know. Is there anyway to make it without using `border`?

```
<style>
#wrapper_1 {
    background-color:pink;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    width: 100px;
}

#wrapper_2 {
    background-color:brown;
    height:100px;
    width: 100px;
    float:right;
}
</style>

<div id="wrapper_1">
    Creating slideshows PHP
</div> 

<div id="wrapper_2">
    Creating slideshows with WordPress 
</div>
```

Comment: without using border seems no..

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can also use pseudo elements to make a vertical separator. You don't need an extra div to make a separator just use the pseudo elements and style it according to your needs.

```css
#wrapper_1 {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
}
#wrapper_1:after {
  content: "";
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  width: 5px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
}
#wrapper_2 {
  background-color: brown;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper_1">
  Creating slideshows PHP
</div>

<div id="wrapper_2">
  Creating slideshows with WordPress
</div>
```

PS: Beware of the absolute positioning of the pseudo elements. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `<hr>`, as it is semantically correct, and then use CSS to convert it to a vertical line.

```
hr.vertical {
    height:100%; /* you might need some positioning for this to work, see other questions about 100% height */
    width:0;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a new div between your two div and add this class:

```
.vertical-row {
 Float:left;
 height:100px;
 width:1px; /* edit this if you want */
 background-color: your color
}
```

Comment: problem here is that height is fixed and not dynamic. maybe that could cause some problems.

Comment: That is right @crack_david. The best way is to modify the above accepted answer slightly, I just added following CSS line to my div left of which I need vertical line and volla, it works like charm "border-left: 2px solid lightgreen;" Hope it helps someone

Comment: thank you this was very easy to implement!

Answer (score 1):

I am not a css hacker but this is how would I do it.. Please notice that you should use `clear: both;` after floating elements.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="container">

  <div id="wrapper_1">
      Creating slideshows PHP
  </div> 

  <div class="seperator"></div>

  <div id="wrapper_2">
      Creating slideshows with WordPress 
  </div>

  <div class="clearfix"></div>

</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#wrapper_1 {
    background-color:pink;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    width: 100px;
}

#wrapper_2 {
    background-color:brown;
    height:100px;
    width: 100px;
    float:right;
}

.seperator {
  height: 100%;
  width: 1px;
  background: black;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}
```

**DEMO**: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rsoj8czx/)

Answer (score 0):

sure you can:

just wrap the elements into a wrapper and make that one display:table-cell.

```
.bigwrapper{
  display:table;
  width:100%;
}
```

second: create another div width class "vr" between your two wrappers and style it as follows:

```
.vr{
  width:1px;
  display:table-cell;
  background-color:black;
  height:100%;

}
```

Final Demo at:

https://plnkr.co/edit/uJsmrCaF9nns49J5RcYj?p=preview

Comment: In your example you can think of the bigwapper is converted into a table. The wrapper_1 and wrapper_2 are converted into table-cells. Now the whole thing behaves like it's a table. Here is a good article: http://colintoh.com/blog/display-table-anti-hero

Answer (score 0):

If you are using flex element and you are having issues with element(s) transforming to columns because of the `display: flex;` property, use the `box-shadow` property on the element as it does not add up to the container space.