# How to put vertical line between two divs?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have `div` where I want to put a vertical line between two other `divs` with some content. How could I do that?

Here is my code.

```css
#vertical-line {
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 1px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-body row" style="padding:0px;margin-top:10px;margin-left:120px;margin-right:120px">

  <div class="col">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <h4>Most popular ads</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin-left:85px;">
      <div class="col">Column</div>
      <div class="col">Column</div>
      <div class="w-100"></div>
      <div class="col">Column</div>
      <div class="col">Column</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="vertical-line">Here goes vertical line</div>

  <div class="col">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <h4>Latest ads</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin-left:85px;">
      <div class="col">Column</div>
      <div class="col">Column</div>
      <div class="w-100"></div>
      <div class="col">Column</div>
      <div class="col">Column</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>
```

Comment: You can use border right for the first div.

Comment: Which version of bootstrap are you using as border right may not work for bootstrap 3 (if your right column is larger than your left)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to add vertical line between two divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36029610/how-to-add-vertical-line-between-two-divs) and many other same posts found by searching SO.

Comment: @Pete I use bootstrap 4

Comment: Border right should be fine then as your columns should be equal heights no matter the content

Comment: @Pete yeah it ads border but I want it to be centered between two divs, and this border is right next to left div

Comment: the two divs touch so it is in the middle of them both:https://www.bootply.com/XaoZgtQEkm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `border-right` instead of `div`:
here is the updated fiddle:

```css
.card-body {
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  padding: 10px;
}

.border-line {
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-body row" style="padding:0px;margin-top:10px;margin-left:120px;margin-right:120px">
  <div class="col border-line">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <h4>Most popular ads</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">Column</div>
      <div class="col">Column</div>
      <div class="w-100"></div>
      <div class="col">Column</div>
      <div class="col">Column</div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="col">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <h4>Latest ads</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">Column</div>
      <div class="col">Column</div>
      <div class="w-100"></div>
      <div class="col">Column</div>
      <div class="col">Column</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>
```

Comment: This adds border right next to left div. And I want that border to be centered between left and right div. Can it be done?

Comment: @Gacho currently it's centre only remove your margins and check. updated fiddle

Answer (score 1):

add `border-right` first `col` class

```
<div class="card-body row" style="padding:0px;margin-top:10px;margin-left:120px;margin-right:120px">
    <div class="col border-right">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/1hucdxeg/1/

Comment: This adds border right next to left div. And I want that border to be centered between left and right div. Is it possible?